# Problems installing packages devtools and callr on Windows

Tags: r, windows, devtools

Installing package `devtools` I obtained the following message

```
There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
         binary source needs_compilation
processx  3.3.1  3.4.0              TRUE
callr     3.2.0  3.3.0             FALSE
```

Moreover:

```
* installing *source* package 'callr' ...
** package 'callr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = 
vI[[j]]) : 
namespace 'processx' 3.3.1 is being loaded, but >= 3.4.0 is required
```

and

```
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'callr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Standard/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/callr'
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘callr’ had non-zero exit status
```

Then I tried to update `processx` package, hoping that it could fix the problem:

```
install.packages("processx")
library(processx)
```

RStudio asked me to restart R session but then

```
> install.packages("devtools")
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'callr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Standard/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/callr'
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘callr’ had non-zero exit status
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** I tried with installing `processx` and `callr` with their dependencies in this way

```
install.packages("processx", dependencies=TRUE)
library(processx)
install.packages("callr", dependencies=TRUE)
library(callr)
```

but I obtained the message:

```
Error in library(callr) : there is no package called ‘callr’
```

Comment: Try installing `processx` and `callr` with their dependencies or/ and then `devtools` with its dependencies.

Comment: Thank you @NelsonGon. Unfortunately I still have problems (see edit in my post).

Comment: What happened at the installation step(s)? Were they successful? Try restarting and check if `callr` exists in `installed.packages()`.

Comment: I checked... It does not exist!

Comment: Hard to know what the issue is, sorry can't help further.

Comment: I have exact same error. This is new for past few weeks.Which R version are you using (3.6.0 here). And which repository? (RStudio here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem. I think your problem is, that latest Rtools version needs to be installed. Devtools will install properly including dependencies to callr and processx after Rtools is installed. So do the following:

1. Delete the callr and processx and devtools packages from your library folder under your Rversion folder.
2. Close Rstudio or R shell.
3. Download recommended version from this site:
   https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/
   Follow instructions here: http://jtleek.com/modules/01_DataScientistToolbox/02_10_rtools/#6
4. After rtools and then devtools are installed, check with find_rtools() if TRUE

Now callr and processx should be installed also as you can see in your library folder.