# RStudio help required for installing the package callr: I can't solve the dependency

Tags: r

I'm a relatively Newbie in using R-Studio, especially reageding to handle the problematic questions. So I appreciate your help and your suggestions - many thanks in advance.

My problem is to understand what's the best way to react onto the installing error below.

- **That's I want to do**
  I want to execute

```
install.packages("callr")
```

Installing the Package callr from CRAN requires the package processx 3.4.0 as a dependency.
But it seems it's only available for my OS Windows10 as an uncompiled version.
Consequence:

> Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
>     namespace 'processx' 3.3.1 is being loaded, but >= 3.4.0 is required
>   ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'callr'
>   removing 'E:/R/R-3.5.1/library/callr'

- **That's I don't understand**
  I don't know what's the best way to solve the dependency.
- **That's I want to do**
  I wanto to use

```
devtools::install_github("rsquaredacademy/pkginfo")
```

and the dependency of installing the package pkginfo is a runing version of the package callr.

**That happened during install process of the package callr**

```
> install.packages("callr")
also installing the dependency ‘processx’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
         binary source needs_compilation
processx  3.3.1  3.4.0              TRUE
callr     3.2.0  3.3.0             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/processx_3.3.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 318959 bytes (311 KB)
downloaded 311 KB

package ‘processx’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\squeezer44\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpm2Hf31\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘callr’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/callr_3.3.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 93115 bytes (90 KB)
downloaded 90 KB

* installing *source* package 'callr' ...
** package 'callr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
  namespace 'processx' 3.3.1 is being loaded, but >= 3.4.0 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'callr'
* removing 'E:/R/R-3.5.1/library/callr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘callr’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\squeezer44\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpm2Hf31\downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems installing packages devtools and callr on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56888506/problems-installing-packages-devtools-and-callr-on-windows)

Answer (score 5):

This instruction should work:

`install.packages(c("processx", "callr"), type = "source")`

but you will need to install [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) first if you don't have it.

Comment: Does that mean in practice: I need to download the uncompiled versions ("processx", "callr") first and build a compiled package afterwards?

Comment: No, you simply need to download and install Rtools, and then paste the command line given above into your R console.

Comment: Thx a lot! - That solved my problem. Either processx and callr are installed in necessary versions.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is solved: processx and callr are installed with the required versions and ready to be used.

**That's what I did**

1. Install Rtools (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)
2. Open RStudio and call that in the console:

   install.packages(c("processx", "callr"), type = "source")
3. RStudio did the rest